# One-night stand and one nightstand

Tags: connotation

I was wondering whether the word nightstand has any sexual connotation. If so, are one-night stand and one nightstand the same thing? I do know that it doesn't actually have any connotation but some people were saying to me that it does so just wanted to check.

Comment: A "one-night nightstand" isn't out of the question, but it would have to be pretty flimsy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The American Heritage Dictionary defines a *[one-night stand](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/one-night+stand)* as

> 1. Slang  a. A sexual encounter that is limited to only one occasion. b. A person that one has such an encounter with.

and a *[nightstand](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nightstand)* as a

> n.  a small table set next to a bed.

so no, the two do not mean the same thing, except to a person with very unusual proclivities.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked with the online OED and it doesn't reference any connotation there.

It says that it's Northern American in origin, giving the definition "A small, low bedside table, typically having drawers" with the first citation being from 1852.

If you're registered with a public library you can use your library card to login. Otherwise I'm not sure you'll be able to view it:

http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/255143

Answer (score -5):

it has sexual connotations. For example [1 night stand](http://onenightstand1.com)  =are casual sexual encounter for one night.

On the other side it could mean also 1 piece of "night stand" (furniture)

Comment: No, it couldn't. There are two different phrases here, with two different meanings - and no ambiguity.

Comment: Please explain if I am missed a point, now I am curious, I was sure that it is as I said, so if that is not problem, please explain :)